# PostgreSQL load existing project's db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i'm setting up a RoR project and i've got a `database.yml` file with a specific database with user and password. What i did was to add this file into my project and want to load it. when i run `rails s` i get an authentication error for the db user. Should i create a new user? should i create the db? Thing is i want to load the records that already exists on it, that's why i'm a little bit lost.

Important fact: i already have a user created with a specific password (for another db) and the username for the new db is the same as my old user (with different password). Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database user can have only one password. Change the password in your `database.yml` to the password of your existing database user.

Comment: Accepted both answers because i had to do both things

Answer (score 0):

You  have to create the database user that's specified in the `database.yml` file.

For Postgres, you have to use [`createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createuser.html) for this. You'll also have to set the corresponding password and then add the proper privileges.

This might help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2.

Then you can run `bin/rails s`. The records won't be deleted.

Comment: how should i create the db specified in the file?

Comment: Rails will create this when you do `bin/rake db:migrate` (which calls `rake db:create`).

Comment: Accepted both answers because i had to do both things